# nslookup issue in Linux

Tags: linux, nslookup

I want to check the host name of particular IP using nslookup in Linux.

When I try to execute

```
nslookup X.X.X.X
```

the following error is showing,

```
** server can't find X.X.X.X.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

give me suggestions to solve this error,

```
#/etc/resolve.conf
Generated by NetworkManager

nameserver 172.17.0.110 
nameserver 172.17.8.55

#netstat -r result
Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
172.19.251.0    *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1  
default         172.19.251.3    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
```

linux nslookup

Comment: Maybe there isn't a PTR record setup for that IP. Not every IP reverses to a hostname.

Comment: This maybe because that IP doesn't have a reverse address.

Comment: how can i add that reverse address and where should i add.

Comment: All depends on where/how this IP is used. Often the forward and reverse data aren't kept at the same place: if you have a server in the cloud, the name-to-address is done by your registrar, but the address-to-name is done by your hosting service.